# MS Graph API - Real time call notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am exploring the MS graph APIs to build integration with MS Teams. In order to do that, I need real-time notifications or information about calling activities like incoming calls, transferred, on hold, hung up etc within.

I read through the MS Graph API documentation a couple of times but couldn't find anything related to it. I came across this [Teamwork - Get System messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/system-messages), and checked how it works. I got a few notifications when the call started in a channel or when a group call started, but it does not send any messages related to a 1-to-1 call.

I also tried the [Communication API Call Records](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-callrecords) APIs, but this is not real-time. It sends the notification 12 mins or so after the call ended.

Has anyone in the community worked with real-time notifications related to calls? If yes, please do share details. Also if it is not possible with MS graph APIs then is there any other way to get real-time updates on calls?

I would really appreciate it if I get any help or pointers on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Please go through the [Working with the cloud communications API in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). Please go through the references [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), [Hung up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), [Transfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-transfer?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Please check this sample to get the real time meeting events - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/meetings-events/csharp

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT Thank you for the response. I am not sure if these will help with real-time notification but I will have one more look at it.